# Reading csv file having japanese text.(C++)

Tags: c++, csv, encoding

A csv file is having japanese text in it. 
On opening through notepad, it says its encoding is utf-8.

I read on stackoverflow, for utf-8 , first read the file in single stream and then convert it into wstring.

I am using below code for the conversion of string to wstring.

```
    wstring stow(const std::string& str){
      int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
      std::wstring wstrTo( size_needed, 0 );
      MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
      return wstrTo;}
```

But still, i am getting junk in the returned wstring in case of japanese text.

Note:

1. I can only use stream to read the csv.
2. No static memory allocation is allowed.

How can i read the Japanese text successfully ?

Comment: Missing checks of both  returned values of `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? What checks you are talking about ?

Comment: `size_needed` is greater than zero. The second call returned the value greater than zero too.

Comment: Can you provide a way to fix it ?

Comment: What to fix, comparison of returned value or skipping BOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is achieved by using CP_ACP encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Missing check to see if UTF-8 BOM is prepended in the string, if yes, skip it.